# Add text for different part of line chart plot in plotly python

Tags: charts, plotly, plotly-python

I draw a figure using plotly (python) as shown in below.
[image]

Now my aim is to show all points in same color but add different text for each colored part from this figure. For example, for the blue part I want to add the text `AAA` and for the red part `BBB`. How to do that in plotly?

Answer (score 1):

- I have simulated data with features that will generate a graph similar to one you have shown
- there are three ways to add labels

  1. labels against traces in legend
  2. as additional scatter plots with `mode="text"`
  3. as annotations on the figure

All three of these are demonstrated below.  It does assume you have a working knowledge of **pandas**

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"AAA":np.concatenate([np.random.uniform(1,5,20), np.full(20,np.nan)]), 
              "BBB":np.concatenate([np.full(20,np.nan), np.random.uniform(1,5,20), ])})

# create two traces, where traces are in legend to label AAA & BBB
fig = px.scatter(df, x=df.index, y=["AAA","BBB"]).update_traces(mode="lines+markers")

# additionally create text trace, that are last AAA & BBB
lastAAA = df.loc[~df["AAA"].isna()].iloc[-1]
lastBBB = df.loc[~df["BBB"].isna()].iloc[-1]
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[lastAAA.name], y=[lastAAA["AAA"]], text="AAA", mode="text", showlegend=False))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[lastBBB.name], y=[lastBBB["BBB"]], text="BBB", mode="text", showlegend=False))

# additionally add annotations
fig.add_annotation(x=lastAAA.name, y=lastAAA["AAA"], text="AAA")
fig.add_annotation(x=lastBBB.name, y=lastBBB["BBB"], text="BBB")
```

[image]